# custom routes not work when defined as "member" in rails 3.2 resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, custom-routes

We need to define 4 custom actions in rails 3.2 app. Those 4 actions take care of creating and edit customer login. In routes.rb, here was addition to routes.rb:

```
member do
  get :new_customer_login
  put :create_customer_login
  get :edit_customer_login
  put :update_customer_login   
end
```

`rake routes` shows the correct route:

```
 new_customer_login_user GET    /users/:id/new_customer_login(.:format)        authentify/users#new_customer_login
create_customer_login_user PUT    /users/:id/create_customer_login(.:format)     authentify/users#create_customer_login
   edit_cutomer_login_user GET    /users/:id/edit_cutomer_login(.:format)        authentify/users#edit_cutomer_login
update_customer_login_user PUT    /users/:id/update_customer_login(.:format)     authentify/users#update_customer_login
```

However when we fired up the spec and there is an no route error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"new_customer_login", :controller=>"authentify/users"}
```

What we did was to change the `member` to `collection` in routes.rb:

```
collection do
  get :new_customer_login
  put :create_customer_login
  get :edit_customer_login
  put :update_customer_login   
end
```

Amazingly, the `no route` error disappeared and the debug hits the `new_customer_login` defined successfully.  We have no clue why `collection` instead of `member` routes work. Those 4 actions are really working on a single record. Can someone provide reasoning why collection but not member works here and how to fix?

Comment: What does your spec look like? Are you passing an ID with the route?

Comment: Yes. Here is the current edit path: edit_customer_login_users_path(id: user.id). Please noted that users is used instead of user.

Answer (score 0):

```
No route matches {:action=>"new_customer_login", :controller=>"authentify/users"}
```

This message actually indicates about insufficient arguments to build a url(id is missing).

Member actions are supposed to route to a single record and collection routes to a collection of records. That's why route helpers for member actions expect to receive a model object or an id as argument.

You should call `new_customer_login_user(user)` in your spec where `user` is a user object.

It also looks like you are defining standard CRUD actions and CustomerLogin is a resource in your project. In that case consider to use nested resources so rails will automatically generate them. See documentation at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources